Python Databricks Dataframe join filtering records unexpectedly
In Azure Databricks I have the following tables:
[File_Processing_History]
Id  bigint
Client  varchar(255)
FileName    varchar(255)
FileType    varchar(3)
EventType   varchar(100)
EventContext    varchar(255)
Checksum    char(40)
OccurredOn  timestamp
Status  varchar(50)
Retry   boolean

[Raw_Data]
XYZFileKey  string
FileName    string
FileContent string

The File_Processing_History table is historical table that tracks the event history of things that happen to files in the system. The Raw_Data table contains raw data extracted from files in our system and has metatdata such as the source file name and contents (data). Both tables have a FileName column that will contain the names of files on the system.
I also have the following Python/Spark code in an Azure Databricks Notebook:
file_processing_df = spark.table("myapp.control.File_Processing_History")
latest_records_df = file_processing_df.join( 
file_processing_df.groupBy("FileName").agg(max("OccurredOn").alias("MaxOccurredOn")),
    on=["FileName"],
    how="inner"
)
result_df = latest_records_df.filter(
    (col("Client") == Client) &
    (col("FileType") == fileType) &
    (col("Status") == "Loaded")
)

windowSpec = Window.partitionBy("FileName").orderBy(col("OccurredOn").desc())
result_df = result_df.withColumn("row_number", F.row_number().over(windowSpec))
filtered_result_df = result_df.filter((col("OccurredOn") == col("MaxOccurredOn")) & (col("row_number") == 1))
filtered_result_df = filtered_result_df.drop("row_number")

filtered_result_df.show()
FileNames = filtered_result_df.select("FileName").distinct()
FileNames.show()
rawDF = spark.table(f"`usurint-mvp`.raw.Raw_Data")
filtered_rawDF = rawDF.join(FileNames, on="FileName", how="inner")
filtered_rawDF.show()

This code is attempting to:

Find all the File_Processing_History rows for the given Client + FileType that not only have the latest OccurredOn date, but that also have Statuses of "Loaded" (if any exists), and save these rows to a dataframe (called filtered_result_df)
Find all the distinct FileNames in that dataframe an store thm in a FileNames dataframe
Select all rows from the FileNames dataframe and select any rows from the Raw_data table whose FileName value matches one of the values in FileNames

When this runs I get the following console output from the shows():
+--------------------+---+-------+--------+--------------+--------------------+--------+--------------------+------+-----+--------------------+
|            FileName| Id| Tenant|FileType|     EventType|        EventContext|Checksum|          OccurredOn|Status|Retry|       MaxOccurredOn|
+--------------------+---+-------+--------+--------------+--------------------+--------+--------------------+------+-----+--------------------+
|z823021-01-04f42s...|175|acme-1|     123|FILE_DECRYPTED|Things were done and...|     N/A|2024-04-09 15:38:...|Loaded|false|2024-04-09 15:38:...|
+--------------------+---+-------+--------+--------------+--------------------+--------+--------------------+------+-----+--------------------+

+--------------------+
|            FileName|
+--------------------+
|z823021-01-04f42s...|
+--------------------+

+--------------+----------+--------------+
|      FileName|XYZFileKey|SourceFileData|
+--------------+----------+--------------+
+--------------+----------+--------------+

Since z823021-01-04f42s... exists in both filtered_result_df and FileNames, I would have expected the filtered_rawDF to be non-empty. Can anyone spot where I'm going awry?

I have created two tables file_processing_df and raw_data_df. Below is the sample data:
+---+-------+--------+--------+---------+------------+--------+----------+------+-----+
| Id| Client|FileName|FileType|EventType|EventContext|Checksum|OccurredOn|Status|Retry|
+---+-------+--------+--------+---------+------------+--------+----------+------+-----+
|  1|Client1|   File1|     CSV|   Loaded|    Context1|   hash1|2022-01-01|Loaded|false|
|  2|Client1|   File1|     CSV|Processed|    Context2|   hash2|2022-01-02|Loaded|false|
|  3|Client1|   File2|     TXT|   Loaded|    Context3|   hash3|2022-01-03|Loaded|false|
|  4|Client2|   File3|     CSV|   Loaded|    Context4|   hash4|2022-01-04|Failed|false|
|  5|Client2|   File3|     CSV|Processed|    Context5|   hash5|2022-01-05|Loaded|false|
+---+-------+--------+--------+---------+------------+--------+----------+------+-----+

+--------+-----------+
|FileName|FileContent|
+--------+-----------+
|   File1|   Content1|
|   File2|   Content2|
|   File3|   Content3|
+--------+-----------+

I have tried the following approach:
latest_records_df = file_processing_df.join( 
    file_processing_df.groupBy("FileName").agg(F.max("OccurredOn").alias("MaxOccurredOn")),
    on=["FileName"],
    how="inner"
)
result_df = latest_records_df.filter(
    (F.col("Client") == Client) &
    (F.col("FileType") == fileType) &
    (F.col("Status") == "Loaded")
)
windowSpec = Window.partitionBy("FileName").orderBy(F.col("OccurredOn").desc())
result_df = result_df.withColumn("row_number", F.row_number().over(windowSpec))
filtered_result_df = result_df.filter(
    (F.col("OccurredOn") == F.col("MaxOccurredOn")) & (F.col("row_number") == 1)
)
filtered_result_df = filtered_result_df.drop("row_number")
filtered_result_df.show()
FileNames = filtered_result_df.select("FileName").distinct()
FileNames.show()
filtered_rawDF = raw_data_df.join(FileNames, on="FileName", how="inner")
filtered_rawDF.show()

Results:
|FileName| Id| Client|FileType|EventType|EventContext|Checksum|OccurredOn|Status|Retry|MaxOccurredOn|
+--------+---+-------+--------+---------+------------+--------+----------+------+-----+-------------+
|   File1|  2|Client1|     CSV|Processed|    Context2|   hash2|2022-01-02|Loaded|false|   2022-01-02|
+--------+---+-------+--------+---------+------------+--------+----------+------+-----+-------------+

+--------+
|FileName|
+--------+
|   File1|
+--------+

+--------+-----------+
|FileName|FileContent|
+--------+-----------+
|   File1|   Content1|
+--------+-----------+

In the above code, I am filtering the latest records with the specified conditions, adding row_number to identify the latest occurrence, and filtering the rows with the latest occurrence. I am also dropping the row_number column, getting the filtered result, obtaining distinct FileNames, and joining with Raw_Data using the distinct FileNames before showing the results.
